Is it true that $e^{i\alpha P + i\beta Q} = e^{i\alpha P}$ on the subspace $P$ acts?
Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a Hilbert space and assume that $\mathscr{H} = H_{1}\oplus H_{2}$, where both $H_{1}, H_{2}$ are mutually orthogonal closed subspaces of $\mathscr{H}$. Suppose we are given self-adjoint operators $P$ and $Q$, with dense domains $D(P) \subset H_{1}$ and $D(Q) \subset H_{2}$, respectively. Assume further that $P: D(P) \to H_{1}$ and $Q: D(Q) \to H_{2}$, that is, they preserve the spaces $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$, respectively.
Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the bounded operator $e^{i\alpha P+i\beta Q}$, defined on $D(P)\oplus D(Q)$. My question is: is it true that, when restricted to $D(P)$, $e^{i\alpha P+i\beta Q}$ reduces to $e^{i\alpha P}$ (and analogously to $e^{i\alpha P+i\beta Q} = e^{i\beta Q}$ on $D(Q)$)? In other words, if $\psi \in D(P)$ then $e^{i\alpha P+i \beta Q}\psi = e^{i\alpha P}\psi$?

How are you defining $e^{i\alpha P + i \beta Q}$?

By the spectral theorem.

Yes. Assume without loss of generality that $\alpha=\beta=1$. Let $E_P$ and $E_Q$ be the spectral measures of $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Define a spectral measure $E=E_P\oplus E_Q$ on $\sigma(P)\cup\sigma(Q)$. Then
$$
\int_{\sigma(P)\cup\sigma(Q)}\lambda\,dE (\lambda)=P+Q.
$$
Then
$$
e^{i (P+Q)}=\int_{\sigma(P)\cup\sigma(Q)}e^{i\lambda}\,dE (\lambda)=e^{i P}+e ^{iQ}.
$$
Then indeed you have
$$
e ^{i (P+Q)}\psi=e ^{i P}\psi,\qquad \psi\in D (P).
$$
